# PHP: getting data from Oracle 10g database

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

I am using wamp server 2.0 working with PHP and my database is Oracle 10g.

I am new to php and I am try to fetch data from database.

There are two columns in my table. I want show 1 column data.
After executing I get only blank page, without data from database (and yes, there is data in my database).

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect("system", "123", "localhost/XE");
if (!$c) {
  echo "Unable to connect: " . var_dump( oci_error() );
  die();
}

$s = oci_parse($c, "select col2 from tab1");
oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);
while ($row =oci_fetch($s)) {
echo $row['name']."<br>";
}

// Commit to save changes...
oci_commit($c);

// Logoff from Oracle...
oci_free_statement($s);
oci_close($c);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need commit if you haven't changed anything?

Comment: should i remove this statement

Comment: definitely, but it will not change anything for your trouble ;-)

Comment: while ($row =oci_fetch($s)) {
echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
this is were problem occurs i assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[oci_fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch.php) copies a result into an internal buffer that you have to access e.g. using [oci_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-result.php).

BTW: Had you set a higher value for [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and turned on [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), then you would have noticed, that you tried to treat a boolean as an array when printing `$row['name']`.

Comment: can tell me a pdf for php with oracle